# Azure CloudService: Adding Diagnostics extension to Role <XYZ> failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-cloud-services, diagnostics

I keep getting this error when I try to enable Diagnostics on a Azure cloud service webrole using Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2015:

> Adding Diagnostics extension to Role  failed: Validation failed
>   on PublicConfig element for the extension with error: The element
>   'Metrics' in namespace
>   'http:schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration'
>   has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected:
>   'MetricAggregation' in namespace
>   'http:schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration'. Microsoft.Cct.StatusWindow.DispatchedStatusItemContainer

This message pops up after I select a storage account en then click OK in the diagnostics configuration.

How can I successfully enable diagnostics?

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUbHW.png)

Comment: Have you installed the latest azure tooling in visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

Why server explorer and not the web role settings? There is what you need and even more - Application Insights.

[image]

Comment: Because we don't use visual studio for deployments but a powershell script.I have updated the script to include the diagnostics configuration via the param "-ExtensionConfiguration" in the call to "New-AzureDeployment" and "Set-AzureDeployment". I agree this is a better solution, but it still bugs me that Visual Studio shows an error like this and provides no hint to what I'm doing wrong. :)